# plot uncommon part of kdeplot

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, graph-visualization

As you can see this code generate that picture:

```
dt=pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 2)), columns=list('AB'))
dt.A=dt.A.apply(lambda x:1 if x<40 else 0)
g = sns.kdeplot(dt["B"][dt["A"] == 0], color="Red", shade = True)
g = sns.kdeplot(dt["B"][dt["A"] == 1], ax =g, color="Blue", shade= True)
```

[image: picture generated with upper code]

How can I plot the uncommon part?
I would like to plot the read part below zero and the blue part upper zero (of course without the purple part).

something like this:

[image: painted by hand]

Comment: So you want red part for `values <= 0` and blue part for `values > 0`?

Comment: @sandeep-kadapa, No, Imagine I would like to plot (blue part)-(red part), so logically when the red part is higher in new plot our line will be under x-axis and when the blue part is higher, the new line will be upper x-axis.